# Create new sql table by entering specific row of specified table in the same database

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables in my database, `MJ100WL`, `WS100WL`, `WS100WW` with identical fields. I am trying to create a new table that reads specific fields from these three tables, with each top row from each of the tables forming a new row in the new table. The fields that need to be included are named `DE_event`, `DE_RMEETI_SCORE` and `DE_name1`.

Would it be able to display this dynamically with php?

Comment: The short answer is "yes".

Comment: "display this"? Yes, php can fetch anything you want from a database and display it.

Comment: What *excatly*  do you mean with "create a new table"? Does that mean that you want to create a new table in your database, using data already stored in your other tables? Or does that mean you want to simply show some data already stored? Also, [*have you tried anything?*](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I am using the SQL query 'code'CREATE TABLE WTOPLIST AS
   SELECT DE_event, DE_RMEETI_SCORE, DE_name1
   FROM MJ100WL LIMIT 1;'code' and it creates it perfectly, but how do I read from the other two table in the same query? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select below will give you columns from top rows of 3 tables

```
SELECT T1.DE_event, 
    , T1.DE_RMEETI_SCORE
    , T1.DE_name1
    , T2.DE_event
    , T2.DE_RMEETI_SCORE
    , T2.DE_name1
    , T2.DE_event
    , T2.DE_RMEETI_SCORE
    , T2.DE_name1
FROM (SELECT DE_event, DE_RMEETI_SCORE, DE_name1 FROM MJ100WL LIMIT 1) AS T1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DE_event, DE_RMEETI_SCORE, DE_name1 FROM WS100WL LIMIT 1) AS T2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DE_event, DE_RMEETI_SCORE, DE_name1 FROM WS100WW LIMIT 1) AS T3
```

What you with them is - create new table, insert into existing one, generate html etc - is up to you

Now that we know what you need :)

```
SELECT DE_event, DE_RMEETI_SCORE, DE_name1 FROM (SELECT DE_event, DE_RMEETI_SCORE, DE_name1 FROM MJ100WL LIMIT 1) AS T1
UNION 
SELECT DE_event, DE_RMEETI_SCORE, DE_name1 FROM (SELECT DE_event, DE_RMEETI_SCORE, DE_name1 FROM WS100WL LIMIT 1) AS T2
UNION 
SELECT DE_event, DE_RMEETI_SCORE, DE_name1 FROM (SELECT DE_event, DE_RMEETI_SCORE, DE_name1 FROM WS100WW LIMIT 1) AS T3
```

Apparently MySql is fussy about 'limit 1' when using UNION. So i wrapped the selects.

Comment: I changed it to include my fields as such: `code`SELECT T1.COL_1
    , T1.COL_2
    , T1.COL_3
    , T2.COL_1
    , T2.COL_2
    , T2.COL_3
    , T3.COL_1
    , T3.COL_2
    , T3.COL_3
FROM (SELECT DE_event, DE_RMEETI_SCORE, DE_name1 FROM MJ100WL LIMIT 1) AS T1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DE_event, DE_RMEETI_SCORE, DE_name1 FROM WS100WL LIMIT 1) AS T2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DE_event, DE_RMEETI_SCORE, DE_name1 FROM WS100WW LIMIT 1) AS T3`code` but I get #1054 - Unknown column 'T1.COL_1' in 'field list'. What should the section under SELECT be in my case?

Comment: I've got it like this now:`code`SELECT T1.DE_event, T1.DE_RMEETI_SCORE, T1.DE_name1, T2.DE_event, T2.DE_RMEETI_SCORE, T2.DE_name1, T3.DE_event, T3.DE_RMEETI_SCORE, T3.DE_name1 FROM (SELECT DE_event, DE_RMEETI_SCORE, DE_name1 FROM MJ100WL LIMIT 1) AS T1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT DE_event, DE_RMEETI_SCORE, DE_name1 FROM WS100WL LIMIT 1) AS T2 CROSS JOIN (SELECT DE_event, DE_RMEETI_SCORE, DE_name1 FROM WS100WW LIMIT 1) AS T3`code` and it works perfectly.

Comment: It however puts all the columns from the three tables next to each other. Is there any way to only display the three headings and then read the fist row from each table under the headings?

Comment: I now get only the three field, but only the first table's data displays.